# How to get last modified time of Recycle Bin

Tags: c#, windows, recycle-bin, datemodified

I've made some basic code attempting to get and display the date modified of the users recycle bin. I have a DateTime which uses File.GetWriteTime on the recycle bin file. Then I'm just displaying that DateTime in a MessageBox. Here is my code:

```
DateTime bin = System.IO.File.GetWriteTime("c:\\$Recycle.bin\\Recycle Bin");
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(bin));
```

It's very basic code that works on other files, however, does not seem to work with the Recycle Bin. When I execute this code, the MessageBox does not display the actual date modified of the bin, however, displays this: **12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM**

After doing a little research I've figured out that this date will be displayed if LastWriteTime returns null or something along the lines of that. The file path is correct so I imagine the error is coming from retrieving the modified date. I'm not sure why this is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please paste your actual code rather than a screenshot of code

Comment: ok I made it code.

Comment: Um, that's not the path to the user's recycle bin.